# Skip to specific linevalue while fileparsing in c++

Tags: c++, readline, conways-game-of-life, fileparsing

I'm writing a fileparser for .lif 105 for Conway's Game of Life.
It works fine, except that I want to skip the text segment above #N, which marks the end of the comments. But this only skips the top three lines for some reason.

Here's an example:

```
#Life 1.05
#D Name: 1 beacon
#D Approximately the 32nd-most common oscillator.
#D www.conwaylife.com/wiki/index.php?title=1_beacon
#N
#P 10 10
..**
.*.*
*..*.**
**.*..*
.*.*
.*..*
..**
```

It will skip lines:

```
#Life 1.05
#D Name: 1 beacon
#D Approximately the 32nd-most common oscillator.
```

Resulting in that the cell segment starts 3 y-cords lower than it should.

```
#include "fileparser.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
string filetype = "#Life 1.05";

void getGame(bool array[100][100], const string& fname){

    // create some objects in memory

    ifstream infile("C:/GameOfLife/ellisonp4hwemulator_105.lif");

    string testType, line;
    int xPos= 0, yPos= 0, temp;

    // read objects

    bool comments = true;
    while (std::getline(infile, line) && comments)
    {
        if(line.find("#N") == std::string::npos)
            comments = false;
    }

    std::getline(infile, line);
    std::istringstream iss(line);



    while(std::getline(infile, line)){
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        iss >> line;
        temp = xPos;
        for(char c : line){
            if(c == '*')
                array[temp][yPos] = true;
            temp++;
        }
        yPos++;
    }

    infile.close(); // optional

}
```

An extra issue for those willing to help some more! Originally I wanted the #P to mark the start co-ords of the cells. So in this case it would start drawing at X-10 Y-10.

But couldn't get it to find it. Here is the code for that, if you want to help some extra :)

```
#include "fileparser.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
string filetype = "#Life 1.05";

void getGame(bool array[100][100], const string& fname){

    // create some objects in memory

    ifstream infile("C:/GameOfLife/ellisonp4hwemulator_105.lif");

    string testType, line, emptyValue;
    int xPos, yPos, temp;

    // read objects

    bool comments = true;
    while (std::getline(infile, line) && comments)
    {
        if(line.find("#N") == std::string::npos)
            comments = false;
    }

    std::getline(infile, line);
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    iss >> emptyValue >> xPos >> yPos;


    while(std::getline(infile, line)){
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        iss >> line;
        temp = xPos;
        for(char c : line){
            if(c == '*')
                array[temp][yPos] = true;
            temp++;
        }
        yPos++;
    }

    infile.close(); // optional

}
```

I want iss >> emptyValue >> xPos >> yPos;

to catch the values emptyValue = #P, xPos = 10, yPos = 10

Thank you for taking your time to read my lengthy question :)

Comment: Re: *"An extra issue"* -- Separate issues belong in separate posts.

Comment: I didn't regard it as an extra issue as they are quite connected :) Sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(line.find("#N") == std::string::npos)
    comments = false;
```

This is the opposite of what you want. The condition will be true if `"#N"` is *not* found. That would be the first line of the file, so that's all the loop reads. Simply switch the operator to `!=`:

```
if(line.find("#N") != std::string::npos)
    comments = false;
```

Actually, the loop will read the next line too, and I don't think that's what you want. You can fix that by switching the order of the condition check in your while loop from this:

```
while (std::getline(infile, line) && comments)
```

to this:

```
while (comments && std::getline(infile, line))
```

Comment: Hehe thanks! Not sure why it was == :)!
Problem now is that it skips 1 line too many, solved it! :D Thank you :)

Comment: @Patidati: refresh the page, I added more information.

Answer (score 0):

In your first function provided, this line

```
if(line.find("#N") == std::string::npos)
```

should be

```
if(!(line.find("#N") == std::string::npos))
```

You want it to set comments to false after this segment is found, not if it is not found

EDIT:

The conditions in the while loop need swapping around too. I just discovered this, unfortunately after Benjamin Lindley - see his answer for details

Comment: Thanks :)! Stupid mistake :)!

Comment: No problem, I can't get the line getting xPos and yPos to work yet though (but I'm sure that's the right way to do it).